# Replace values only in specified columns if ==0

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data that looks like this:

> ```
>   ID Married Age Visits
> 1  1       0  35      0
> 2  2       1   0      7
> 3  3       0  29     19
> ```

```
df <- data.frame(
          ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L),
     Married = c(0L, 1L, 0L),
         Age = c(35L, 0L, 29L),
      Visits = c(0L, 7L, 19L)
)
```

Imagine that for this data, `Married` is meant to be a dummy variable, but `Age` and `Visits` should definitely not be 0. I would like to know how to do two things:

1. How can I replace, only in columns `Age` and `Visits`, replace NA for the 0 values?
2. How can I replace, only in columns `Age` and `Visits`, replace -999 for the 0 values? This one is just for curiosity, because I'd like to know how to do it without using `na_if()`.

This code isn't quite right, because it changes the Married column also.

```
df <- na_if(df, 0)
```

giving:

> ```
>   ID Married Age Visits
> 1  1      NA  35     NA
> 2  2       1  NA      7
> 3  3      NA  29     19
> ```

whereas, what I would like is (1):

> ```
>   ID Married Age Visits
> 1  1       0  35     NA
> 2  2       1  NA      7
> 3  3       0  29     19
> ```

and (2):

> ```
>   ID Married Age Visits
> 1  1       0  35    -999
> 2  2       1  -999    7
> 3  3       0  29     19
> ```

I tried something like:

```
df <- na_if(c(df$Age, df$Visits), 0))
```

but that's not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a dplyr solution to your problem.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(Age,Visits),funs(na_if(.,0)))
df %>% mutate_at(vars(Age,Visits),funs(ifelse(. == 0,-999,.)))
```

Comment: For some reason, I had it in my head that the `funs()` part of `mutate_at` had been deprecated to `list()`, but when I tried `list()` it didn't work. Your code worked perfectly. Can you explain the difference between `funs()` and `list()`, please?

Comment: That's not the case as far as I'm aware. The `funs()` argument specifies the functions that you want to apply to the variables in `vars()`. For details, see the dplyr documentation: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/scoped.html.

Answer (score 3):

You could do

Solution 1)

```
library(dplyr)
cols <- c("Age", "Visits")
df[cols] <- na_if(df[cols], 0)

df
#  ID Married Age Visits
#1  1       0  35     NA
#2  2       1  NA      7
#3  3       0  29     19
```

Solution 2)

```
df[cols][df[cols] == 0] <- -999

df
#  ID Married  Age Visits
#1  1       0   35   -999
#2  2       1 -999      7
#3  3       0   29     19
```

Similar to Solution 2) you could also do Solution 1) as

```
df[cols][df[cols] == 0] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

```
df$Age[is.na(df$Age)] <- 0
df$Age[df$Age == -999] <- 0
```